# Cakephp 2 - check if a user is logged in view

Tags: cakephp, view, authentication

I need a display element according to whether the user is logged or not - In CakePHP 2.0

This does not work

```
<?php
  if ($this->Auth->loggedIn() 
    { 
    echo $this->element('user');
    }

  else 
    {
    echo $this->element('guest');
    } 
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Follow the MVC pattern and put the logic in the controller.

In the controller:

```
$this->set( 'loggedIn', $this->Auth->loggedIn() );
```

In the view:

```
if( $loggedIn ) { 
    echo $this->element( 'user' );
}
else {
    echo $this->element( 'guest' );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the session helper (required for authentication as showed in the "log tutorial") :

```
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
    echo 'logged';
} else {
    echo 'guest';
}
```

Comment: i always use `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')` explicitly (the id should never be empty, but i guess you never know).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$element = (AuthComponent::loggedIn()) ? 'user' : 'guest';
echo $this->element($element);
```

Pretty similar to what you already tried, but then calling the loggedIn method statically.

Comment: this raises `Error: Call to undefined method View::user()`

Answer (score 0):

```
!$this->Session->check('marketplace_showlink'
```

if error occures in the above code which is coded in `appcontroller`

like:
    **Call to a member function check() on a non-object**

it will generate due to Empty session variable